# JVM process parent

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, jboss, jvm

I'm creating a process with processBuilder in java program in Ubuntu :

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(CHROME_UBUNTU_PATH, "--headless","--enable-logging", "--disable-gpu","--print-to-pdf=" + filePath + ".pdf","file:///" + absolutePath);
pb.start();
```

But chrome wouldn't start cause it's running with the user root :

```
Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.
```

So I started my Jboss with a non root user but in the sudoers group

But still the same error appears.

What should I do ?

Comment: So why aren't you adding the option it tells you to use in the error-message?

Comment: cause I don't want to use that, and I want to undrestant why it's runned by a root user

Comment: Check the user the JBoss process runs with. Maybe it changed it in order to be able to open serversockets with ports < 1024.